# Karma unit testing of controller using service. Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and trying to test my controller which is using a service but  keep getting 'undefined' with '$scope.order', '$scope.stock' and all the functions included in my controller. I have tested the service separately all tests passing there but can't get my head around controller testing. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Would be grateful is somebody could guide me a little bit.

controller.js

```
angular.module('shop.controllers', [])


.controller('StockCtrl', function($scope, Stock) {
   $scope.stock = Stock.all();
   $scope.order = Stock.order();

   $scope.showTotalPrice = function() {
    $scope.total = Stock.total();
 }

   $scope.addToBasket = function(chatId){
    Stock.update(chatId);
    Stock.updateBasket(chatId); 
 }
});
```

service.js

```
angular.module('shop.services', [])

.factory('Stock', function() {

  var order = [];
  var prices = [];
  var total = 0;
  var items = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Black Shoes",
    price: 50,
    quantity: 7
},
{ 
    id: 1,
    name: "Blue Shoes",
    price: 10,
    quantity: 2
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Green Shoes",
    price: 14,
    quantity: 5
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Red Flip Flops",
    price: 9,
    quantity: 6
}

}];

return {
all: function() {
  return items;
},
get: function(itemId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id === parseInt(itemId)) {
      return items[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
},
update: function(itemId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id === parseInt(itemId)) {
      return items[i].quantity -= 1;
    }
  }
  return null;
},
updateBasket: function(itemId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id === parseInt(itemId)) {
      order.push({name: items[i].name, price: items[i].price});
      prices.push(items[i].price);    
    }
  }
 return null;
},
order: function() {
  return order;
},
total: function() {
  return total = eval(prices.join('+')); 
},

};
});
```

controller.spec.js

```
describe('Controllers', function(){
var scope;
var control;
var StockMock;


beforeEach(module('shop.controllers'));

beforeEach(function(){
    StockMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('Stock', ['all', 'get', 'update', 'updateBasket', 'order'])

    inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      control = $controller('StockCtrl', {$scope: scope, Stock: StockMock});
   });
 });


  it("should have a scope variable defined", function() {
    expect(scope).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
beforeEach(module('shop.controllers'));
```

You should add the application module instead of controller module.

```
beforeEach(module('shop'));
```